# regex for email validation Not Working with Subdomains?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following for email validation:

```
var filter = /^([\w]+)(.[\w]+)*@([\w]+)(.[\w]{2,3}){1,2}$/; // For Email Validation

if (filter.test(emailInputVal))) {console.log('good')}
```

For some reason the above does not work with emails that have a subdomain Any ideas why?

```
xxxx@xxx.xxx.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your regular expression is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
var filter = /^\w+(?:\.\w+)*@\w+(?:\.\w+)+$/;
```

This link may help you lots when validating email addresses:

> http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

### Official RFC 2822 standard

This non-trivial simplified regular expression conforming to RFC 2822 standard:

```
var filter = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b/;
```

Comment: @AnApprentice: Don't forget to check the link I attached which shows several email cheking regular expressions and explains email validation using regular expressions in depth.

Comment: doesn't handle quotes and will break with new top-level domains; as you'll probably send a confirmation mail anyway, why not use a less strict expression?

Answer (score 2):

That is one weird regex. It's certainly not doing what you're expecting it to do, for example because the dot isn't escaped when you do mean a literal dot.

Since it's impossible to really validate an email address with a regex anyway - why not go for something simpler?

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i
```

This will still match some invalid addresses and will reject some valid addresses (as all readable regexes do), but in the end you have to send a confirmation mail to a user-submitted mail address and see if you get a reply if you truly want to validate it.

Comment: why reject valid addresses when you have to send a confirmation mail (possibly after checking the DNS record on the server-side) anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably validate email addresses with regular expressions. What I'd do:

- use a simple expression like `/^[^@]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/` for client-side validation to catch typos
- check the DNS record on the server-side
- send a confirmation mail

Comment: adding support for quoted strings slightly complicates the expression: `/^("(\\"|[^"])*"|[^@\s]+)@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/` should do it...

Answer (score 0):

Your last component is: any length word, then one or two instances of (dot, two-or-three-letter word).   I would expect "xxxx@xxx.xxx.com" to work, but perhaps not more realistic examples like "xxxx@xxx.example.com" because your domain name is not a two-or-three-letter word.

Do yourself a favor: use simply `/^[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ ]+$/`  More about this: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200908/humane_email_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above code will work any format, because there is an extra ) in the if condition, removing it works for the sub domain too:

```
if (filter.test(emailInputVal)) {console.log('good')}
```