# What regex is good for email validation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following for email validation:

```
var filter = /^(\w+)(\.\w+)*@(\w+)(\.\w+)+$/;
```

Just noticed that it does not support xxxx+wildcard@gmail.com (it does not support the +wildcard part). Any way to get that added?

Comment: It also doesn't support other common email characters like numbers, dashes, or underscores.

Comment: My bad.  `\w` does include numbers and underscores, but does it include dashes?  Example: `an.apprentice@experts-exchange.com`

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727145/regex-for-email-validation-not-working-with-subdomains/4727363#4727363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked SLak's answer.  I actually have a regular expression I wrote awhile back that's even more open-ended.

```
^.+@.+\..+$
```

The idea behind it is similar.  Don't try so hard.  Instead, err on the side of accepting too much.  To my knowledge this regex should accept every conceivable valid email address (and some invalid ones as well).

Comment: But that's still rejecting the wildcards which is the issue right? adsasd+123@gmail.com gets rejected

Comment: No, the + is fine.  Here are test cases... http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=4b398738-f887-4eb1-817a-09398ca30c43

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\S+@\S+\.\S+`, which will match anything with an `@` and a `.`.
Anything more than that will reject valid but obscure addresses.

Even this will reject valid but obscure addresses, such as `"Test Me"@localhost`.
However, these are never used in practice. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Comment: Ya but that is rejecting the wildcards +

Comment: @AnA: This will not reject `+`.